# net core api controller unit testing using xunit and moq

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

i have some api controller methods that i would like to add some unit tests to. I am using xunit and moq and writing in c# using asp net core.

example of one method is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<StatusDTO>>> Get()
{
    return await _statusservice.GetStatusesAsync();
}
```

at this point in time my controller method is simply returning the dto that the service layer method is returning. In future it might change to return a specific viewmodel.

i have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.2 to get some guidance on testing controllers.

My question is : for example above would the unit test just consist of 
- checking that the return type is `ActionResult<StatusDTO>` and/or (using moq) verifying the service method has been called.

Should i set up my service method to return a mock `StatusDTO` and do some assertions against that. I don't see benefit of that in this situation, as that would be testing the service method wouldn't it and i would cover that in the service method tests.

Sorry if this seems quite basic - my knowledge and experience in writing unit tests is very limited.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't be unit testing controllers. There's caveats, but hence the "in general". It might be appropriate, for example, to unit test a particular method of a controller if you have some helper method on it, but actions are generally too complex to be reliably unit tested.

There's an `HttpContext`, an `ActionContext`, `Session`, `User`, etc. - all dependencies that might be potentially utilized in various ways and all of which would need to be satisfied via mocks. Sure, you could mock all the dependencies, but by the time you've done that, your test code is 100 times longer than your actual application code, and ultimately whether your test ends up passing or failing begins to have more to do with whether you've correctly mocked everything than whether or not your actual application code is correct.

Then, particularly in this scenario, your action is only doing one thing: calling a method on a service class. The service class is what should be unit tested, and assuming it is united tested, then adding a unit test for this action adds nothing.

Long and short, actions lend themselves better to integration testing. You should factor out as much of the action logic as possible into methods or classes that can be individually unit tested (which you've already done), and then you simply test the integration, i.e. that a particular request results in a particular response.

For more information on integration testing in ASP.NET Core, see the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It's geared more towards Razor Pages, but the methodology is the same whether you're integration testing a Razor Page, an MVC action, or an  API action. It's all just a request that results in a response.